# Neat way to define high order function without specifying input type

Tags: scala, syntax, functional-programming

I want to be able to define such a nice receive function in scala

```
sealed trait DoParent
case object DoThis extends DoParent
case object DoThat extends DoParent

object MyApp extends App {

  val receive = {
    case DoThis => println("dothis")
    case DoThat => println("dothat")
  }


  receive(DoThis)

}
```

but it generates

```
missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: ?
  val receive = {
                ^
```

I now I understand it asks me to add the type but i want the receive to look as neat and clean (define only the cases inside as shown without the types) as actors receive looks like, what am i missing?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is a way around the type specification. The way actors do it is they declare receive in parent trait such as:

```
trait WithReceive {
    def receive:PartialFunction[DoParent, Unit] //for some reason this needs to be a def
}
```

And then have your object inherit from that trait:

```
object MyApp extends App with WithReceive {
    def receive = { //this needs to be a def too
        case DoThis => ???
        case DoThat => ???
    }
}
```

For some reason it needs to be a def, using val results in the same error you got.

Comment: There was just a long ML thread about why it must be a def: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-language/1FMHSbGkIMw/ZMGfcugZFCIJ with issue https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2742 so maybe soon the val's RHS will also be typechecked with the type in the trait.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly:

```
val receive: DoParent => Any = {
  case DoThis => println("dothis")
  case DoThat => println("dothat")
}

receive(DoThis)
receive(DoThat)
```

Output:

```
dothis
dothat
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while you "know" that you want the argument to be of type `DoParent`, the Scala compiler doesn't. You could want it to accept for example `Any`... That's why you must annotate your function value with a type:

```
val receive: DoParent => Unit = {
  case DoThis => println("dothis")
  case DoThat => println("dothat")
}
```

You could also use a method instead of a function value:

```
def receive(x: DoParent) = x match {
  case DoThis => println("dothis")
  case DoThat => println("dothat")
}
```